# Where do we find our reviews in iTunes App Store?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore

Is there a place where we can find our own comments in the iTunes App Store so we see how many consider our comments as good ones for example?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reviews are available from Store->View My Account, then check the "Manage >" link after the "Reviews and Ratings" text in the "Settings" section of the page.